# Having trouble with char* arrays

Tags: c++

```
private:
    char * args[];
public:
    Command(char * a[]){args = a}
```

When trying to run this code I get

> incompatible types in assignment of `char**` to `char* [0]`

I am having real trouble understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `char * args[];` is incorrect. In standard C++ an array has to have a specified size when defined. The (apparent) exception is when you write something like `int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`, however in this case the compiler automatically sets the size to 5 in this case, as it determines the size at compile time.

Secondly, you cannot copy an array. In your function

```
Command(char * a[]){args = a}
```

`a` decays to a `char**`. Then you are trying to assign to `args`, which is an array, a pointer of type `char**`. This won't work. You cannot assign to an array.

In case you assign/copy arrays, your best bet is to use standard containers such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Re `char* arr[] = "something"`, no, that's not a possibility. Also, an array doesn't have to "have a specified size" in all contexts.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry, typo, changed the type for more clarity. And yes, you're right, you can have non-specified sizes in templates, or even in typedefs, thanks for the comment, edited.

Comment: i will be using vectors

Comment: @walton BTW, if one of the answers here address your question to your satisfaction, you should accept it in the future, so other users of this site see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `char * args[]` denotes an array of pointers to non-`const` `char`. It's invalid code. Standard C++ does not permit an array of unknown bound as a data member.

Raw arrays are not assignable so also the assignment in the constructor body is invalid code.